# iOS 13.1 UITextView delegate method shouldInteract only called when long pressing on attachment

Tags: ios, uitextview

Last month, I posted one question about interacting with the link in UITextView ([iOS 13.1 UITextView delegate method shouldInteract called when scrolling on attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189447/ios-13-1-uitextview-delegate-method-shouldinteract-called-when-scrolling-on-atta)).

The Good news is the issue was fixed in iOS 13.2 and the bad news is they introduce a new bug about attachment interaction, that is, the attachment interaction method `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)` only called when long pressing on the attachment.

I have filed a bug and hoping Apple will fix this issue in the next iOS release.

Is there any workaround for this issue?